# Linux emoji input

Tags: gratis, linux, offline, input-method

When preparing a message on Linux, I often want to write rare emoji such as  or .

To insert the emoji, I open a web browser and search for "penguin emoji" or "tokyo tower emoji", then copy from the first website in the results. It takes a few precious seconds.

Is there a faster way to insert emoji, for Linux?

A standalone program is OK, but something as unintrusive and lightweight to the [compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) would be the best. Unlike the compose key, it must allow for searching and show several results, because when I search for "rabbit" I want to be able to choose between  and .

- Gratis, ideally open source.
- Ideally should work offline, with a local search index.

Comment: Gnome > 3.28 can do it. See https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/06/use-emoji-linux-ubuntu-apps

Comment: Or [Emoji Keyboard](https://github.com/OzymandiasTheGreat/emoji-keyboard).

Comment: Wonderful! I had no idea? Please post two answers with screenshots and links so that I can upvote them. Or I can write the answer if you have no time :-)

Comment: Feel free to write the answers, as I did not test either of these tools myself ...

Answer (score 5):

## Albert

Try [albert](https://github.com/albertlauncher/albert) with [Python Extensions](https://github.com/albertlauncher/python).

It looks good and modern. It works independent of any other program. You simply use a hotkey to call albert overlay, type `:` and then a substring of an emoji description. It also shows you the recently used emojis after typing only `:`. To use the chosen emoji, use <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it is automatically sent to the clipboard. Then you use <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> to paste it.

[image]

It's fast and works flawlessly for me.  ✅

#### Installation

I installed [albert](https://github.com/albertlauncher/albert) from sources. I think it is a more stable option in this case. There should be little problem on Debian-based systems as they listed the needed libraries in a comfortable fashion.

> @lacostenycoder reported that you should also install **ImageMagick**. To do that, on Ubuntu-based distros run

> ```
> sudo apt install imagemagick -y
> ```

After you install albert, download [Python Extensions](https://github.com/albertlauncher/python) and launch albert, you click the gear in the corner and go to *Extensions* tab, where you find *Python* section and Unicode Emojis extension. You enable it and you're ready to use it.

#### Experienced issues

Some of the emojis don't render correctly  ❌.

[image]

I don't know if it is a fault of albert or a font, though ‍♂️.

<s>Albert is not maintained since 2019 , but it still works well (2020).</s>

Development relaunched in November 2020.

## Emote

Now we also have  [Emote](https://github.com/tom-james-watson/Emote), which allows to pick an emoji using a keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+E</kbd> by default.

[image: Emote interface]

There are also categories. It lets you choose the skin color as well (the hand in the top-right corner). An issue I encountered is that the keyboard shortcut stopped working on X11.

Comment: This is great and I already love Albert. But I get an error when I try to enable the extension, it's grayed out and says `missing dependancies:no 'convert' in $PATH` any ideas? I'll try reboot, but not sure.

Comment: I found the answer, needed to just do `sudo apt install imagemagick` and restart Albert, now this works!!! Thanks this will save me lots of time!!!

Answer (score 0):

Gnome has that feature since 2018, and it is active by default in many distributions such as Ubuntu.

1. Open Ubuntu's Text Editor app
2. Right-click in the text area
3. Click "Insert Emoji"
4. Type in the search box
5. Choose one of the emojis that come up

[image: rabbit emoji gnome]

Unfortunately it is not available in many non-Gnome-centric apps such as Firefox, LibreOffice or Geany.

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/06/use-emoji-linux-ubuntu-apps

Thanks pLumo for the tip!

Comment: that's a lot of steps if you're doing something else and want to type an emoji

Comment: @lacostenycoder I totally agree! Really looking forward to any better solution.

Comment: See the answer above your using Albert. I got it working like a charm!